# how to make a vistor counter with html and js

Tags: javascript, html, hitcounter

i would like to count all the people that come to my website and display it on my page, i have researched visitor counters but they only seem to count me going to the website not all the people (from other computers). I dont have any code (on the counnter currently) because im not good with js, help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot have a counter using client side JS only. You need some storage on the server

Comment: You need to record the stats on the server, and then have your JS request those stats when the page is loaded. Or simply have those stats embedded in the page when the server creates the page. It depends on what tech you're using.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, [search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+visitor+counter+javascript+only+site:stackoverflow.com)